# Trying to print 1 or 2 depending on whether a number is in the array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, search

I am trying to print 1 if a number is found and 0 if it is not found.

My code int search(int a[], int n, int key, int **loc) looks through an array and returns 0 or 1.

However I am getting 4195632 when I run it.

I assume that number has to do with addresses but don't know what I'm doing wrong

a[5] is the array

n = is the size of the array

key is the element I am looking for

**loc is supposed to be the pointer to the first location of the search key in array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[5] = {5,3,7,2,9};
int n = 5;
int key = 5;
int **loc = 0;

int search(int a[], int n, int key, int **loc)
{
    int x;
    for(x = **loc; x < n; x++)
    {
        if(a[x] == key)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",search);
}
```

Also I'm not sure what **loc does. I know it has to do with pointers, but I think I have to use this because this is homework.

Comment: You need a decent C book. Functions don't work like you think they do...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat every other program i wrote in C worked pretty similar to java so I wrote it kind of like java lol

Comment: @i_want_to_die  It is not clear what is the purpose of the variable loc?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I want to use loc as a counter pointer for the for loop. For example in a java for loop for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++). I need to use loc as 0 because I apparently have to

Comment: Java and C are different languages.   If you try to learn C by analogy with Java, some things will work.  But, eventually, you will encounter cases where the Java constructs aren't valid C (as in this case) or - worse - they are valid constructs but work completely differently.   If you want to learn C, you are better off learning C, rather than trying to write Java code in C and puzzle out the differences.

Comment: Setting `loc` to 0 means it doesn't point to anything. Attempting to dereference it later (with `**loc`) can't be good.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you mean the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int search( const int a[], size_t n, int key, size_t *loc )
{
    *loc = 0;

    while ( *loc < n && a[*loc] != key ) ++*loc;

    return *loc != n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 5, 3, 7, 2, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int key = 5;
    size_t loc;

    if ( search( a, N, key, &loc ) )
    {
        printf( "%d is found at position %zu\n ", key, loc );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 is found at position 0
```

If it is necessary that the last parameter had the type `int **` then the function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int search( const int a[], size_t n, int key, int **loc )
{
    *loc = ( int * )a;

    while ( *loc != a + n && **loc != key ) ++*loc;

    return *loc != a + n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 5, 3, 7, 2, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int key = 5;
    int *loc;

    if ( search( a, N, key, &loc ) )
    {
        printf( "%d is found at position %zu\n ", key, ( size_t)(loc - a) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is strange but the output is the same as in the above program

```
5 is found at position 0
```

Comment: thanks for this, but I need to use **loc. 

I will try out your program replacing * loc with ** loc but I don't think that is how this C thing works

Answer (score 0):

Learn a bit of C first.

What you get is the address (on 64 bit system only a part of it) of the function search, but you do not call this function.

**loc is the start index position when you search the array.